# When compiling, the simulator does not start in Xcode on Apple MacBook Pro M1

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-simulator, apple-m1

When I create a new project everything works fine

But when I try to run a project from my repository which was create on another MacBook , the build is successful, but the simulator simply does not react to it at all

Answer (score 0):

might be a dumb answer, but did you select iPhone or iPad in the simulator setting? sometimes simulator is set to `Any iOS Devices`